# Query elements in System.Xml.Linq.XElement

Tags: c#

C# code:

```
List<XElement> ele = reportHost.hostProperties.ToList();          
foreach (var item in ele)
{
 Console.WriteLine("XML: {0}", item);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```xml
<HostProperties>
  <tag name="cpe">cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel</tag>
  <tag name="device">1234567</tag>
  <tag name="FQN">BOB-PC</tag>
  <tag name="Domain">Internal</tag>
 </HostProperties>
```

How can I expand the code above to extract the values "BOB-PC" and "1234567" for the XML output above?

Comment: var elements = ele.Where(x => x.Value == "BOB-PC" || x.Value == "1234567"); I believe that would work. Didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. These values will not be static and will change, so what could I use to extract the values based on the attribute name (e.g. cpe, device, FQN, or Domain)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ele` is a collection of `<HostProperties>` elements. You can use Linq to Xml to check the value of the `name` attribute to get the correct values of the element. If you are getting null references, you will have to add additional null checks - as I don't know what is required or not in the xml.

```
List<XElement> hostProperties = reportHost.hostProperties.ToList(); 

// iterate through each <hostProperties> element
foreach (var hp in hostProperties)
{
    // all of the <tag> elements
    var tags = hp.Element("HostProperties").Elements("tag");

    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
      // get the attribute with the name of "name"
      var tagName = tag.Attribute("name");

      // check to make sure a <tag> element exists with a "name" attribute
      if (tagName != null)
      {
        if (tagName.Value == "device")
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"device: {tag.Value}");
        }
        else if (tagName.Value == "fqn")
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"fqn: {tag.Value}");
        }
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Getting a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Attribute(...) returned null.

Comment: does the the `Console.WriteLine("XML: {0}", item);` produce the entire xml snippet in your question, i.e the `<HostProperties>....</HostProperties/>`?

Comment: yes it does. Should also be noted that sometimes a particular tag name may not exist, as the reportHost List sits in another reportHosts XElement lists (contain many Hosts and Properties). So sometimes a particular tag name may not exist. Tried to include a || !=null in if statement but it does not allow. Hope that makes sense. I am basically parsing a Nessus XML file (output from a vulnerability scanner.

Comment: updated my answer. If you are still getting null reference exceptions, then you should debug this to find out where and add additional null checks